# Numba fast math does not improve speed

Tags: performance, numpy, math, cpu, numba

I run the following code with `fastmath` option enabled and disabled.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit
from threading import Thread
import time
import psutil
from tqdm import tqdm


@jit(nopython=True, fastmath=True)
def compute_angle(vectors):
    return 180 + np.degrees(np.arctan2(vectors[:, :, 1], vectors[:, :, 0]))



cpu_usage = list()
times = list()

# Log cpu usage
running = False
def threaded_function():
    while not running:
        time.sleep(0.1)
    print("Start logging CPU")
    while running:
        cpu_usage.append(psutil.cpu_percent())
    print("Stop logging CPU")
thread = Thread(target=threaded_function, args=())
thread.start()


iterations = 1000

# Generate frames
vectors_list = list()
for i in tqdm(range(iterations), total=iterations):
    vectors = np.random.randint(-50, 50, (500, 1000, 2))
    vectors_list.append(vectors)

for i in tqdm(range(iterations), total=iterations):
    s = time.time()
    compute_angle(vectors_list[i])
    e = time.time()
    times.append(e - s)
    # Do not count first iteration
    running = True

running = False

thread.join()

print("Average time per iteration", np.mean(times[1:]))
print("Average CPU usage:", np.mean(cpu_usage))
```

The results with `fastmath=True` are:

```
Average time per iteration 0.02076407738992044
Average CPU usage: 6.738916256157635`
```

The results with `fastmath=False` are:

```
Average time per iteration 0.020854528721149738
Average CPU usage: 6.676455696202531
```

Should I expect some gain since I am using mathematical operations?
I also tried to install `icc-rt` but I am not sure how to check if it is enabled or not.
Thank you!

Comment: Your code is just a couple of simple calls to `numpy`, and those calls are already heavily optimized.  You're getting 500,000 arctan calls in 20ms, which is 25,000,000 per second.  You need to be realistic in your expectations.

Comment: Using `np.degrees` is not efficient. Doing it yourself will be faster (because of FMA and fastmath). `np.arctan2` will not be very fast here because of the strided memory accesses which likely prevent the use of SIMD instructions.

Comment: Theoretically, would it make any difference to use floating-point 16 instead of 32 or 64 on CPU? Will they save memory at least of are they still stored as 32 or 64 bits?

Comment: @JérômeRichard At least if you set `assert vectors.shape[2]==2` you can avoid the issue with the unknown memory layout (the striding isn't really a problem).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few things missing to get the SIMD vectorization working. For maximum performance it is also necessary to avoid costly temporary arrays, which may not be optimized away if you use a partly vectorized function.

- Function calls have to be inlined
- The memory access pattern must be known at compile time. In the following example this is done with `assert vectors.shape[2]==2`. Generally the shape of the last array could also be larger than two, which would be much more complicated to SIMD-vectorize.
- Division by zero checks can also avoid SIMD-vectorization, and are slow if they are not optimized away. I do this manually by calculating `div_pi=1/np.pi` once and than a simple multiplication inside the loop. If a repeated division is not avoidable you can use `error_model="numpy"` to avoid the division by zero check.

**Example**

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(fastmath=True)
def your_function(vectors):
    return 180 + np.degrees(np.arctan2(vectors[:, :, 1], vectors[:, :, 0]))

@nb.njit(fastmath=True)#False
def optimized_function(vectors):
    assert vectors.shape[2]==2

    res=np.empty((vectors.shape[0],vectors.shape[1]),dtype=vectors.dtype)
    div_pi=180/np.pi
    for i in range(vectors.shape[0]):
        for j in range(vectors.shape[1]):
            res[i,j]=np.arctan2(vectors[i,j,1],vectors[i,j,0])*div_pi+180
    return res
```

**Timings**

```
vectors=np.random.rand(1000,1000,2)

%timeit your_function(vectors)
#no difference between fastmath=True or False, no SIMD-vectorization at all
#23.3 ms ± 241 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit optimized_function(vectors)
#with fastmath=False #SIMD-vectorized, but with the slower (more accurate) SVML algorithm
#9.03 ms ± 120 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
#with fastmath=True  #SIMD-vectorized, but with the faster(less accurate) SVML algorithm
#4.45 ms ± 14.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Why not pre-multiplying `div_pi` by 180? Besides this, note that moving `180*div_pi` *in the beginning* of the expression should be a bit faster without faster (due to floating-point non-associativity without fast-math). Finally, is it documented somewhere that Numba take benefits from assertions? AFAIK, Clang developers are working on this but the last time I looked it had not been mainlined or fully used.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I don't know this detail from the documentation. The issue was discussed somewhere in a github issue (approx. 2-3 years ago). It is supported for quite a long time and can be also beneficial for automatic unrolling of small inner loops. Regarding clang: I am not so experienced with C. But isn't something like that `...double vectors[][vec_shape_1][2]...` not working quite the same way? (Doing the checking manually?)

Comment: Thank you very much. I have two questions left for you. Where did you learn all this stuff? And what do you mean by `Function calls have to be inlined`?

Comment: Also @max9111, suppose that `vectors.shape[0]` and `vectors.shape[1]` represent the height and width of a video: their value will be constant during an execution but can be different between executions (depending on the input video). Is there a way to SIMD-vectorize this like you did with `assert vectors.shape[2] == 2`?

Comment: @user1315621 The last dimension is usually the one which is important.