# What causes the slowdown in this numba code?

Tags: python, numba

I have the following simple function the sums the values in the 2nd row or an array:

```
@njit('float64(float64[:, ::1], uint64, uint64)', fastmath=True)
def fast_sum(array_2d, start, end):
    s = 0.0
    for i in range(start, end):
        s += array_2d[1][i]
    return s
```

I time it with:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit
A = np.random.rand(2, 500)
%timeit fast_sum(A, 100, 300)
```

This gives me:

```
%timeit fast_sum(A, 100, 300)
304 ns ± 17.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
```

In fact I want to include the value at index `end` so I change the function to be:

```
@njit('float64(float64[:, ::1], uint64, uint64)', fastmath=True)
def fast_sum_v2(array_2d, start, end):
    s = 0.0
    end = end + 1
    for i in range(start, end):
        s += array_2d[1][i]
    return s
```

The code now runs 40% more slowly!

```
%timeit fast_sum_v2(A, 100, 299)
423 ns ± 6.93 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
```

My guess is that this is because adding 1 to end changes the type of end. But is that really right?

Comment: Not that I expect it to make any difference, but the second test should be `fast_sum_v2(A, 100, 299)` because otherwise the loop has one more iteration than the first test. And you might want to add a sum operation of an unrelated variable to the first test as well. Again, I don't expect these to explain the entire performance difference.

Comment: @GuyIncognito Thanks. I didn't quite understand your second suggestion. Can you show the code you have in mind?

Comment: The second function has an operation that the first function doesn't have (`end = end + 1`). You could add for example `tmp = 0` and then `tmp = tmp + 1` to the first function (and hope that it won't get optimized away) so that the time it takes to execute `end = end + 1` doesn't affect the test.

Comment: @GuyIncognito numba uses -03 under the hood so I am pretty certain that would just be removed by the optimizer.

Comment: Without the `fastmath` argument, times are nearly equal.

Comment: @MichaelButscher That is even more mysterious. You can see the assembly with inspect_asm() but I find it hard to understand.

Comment: I could only see that the asm code for `fast_sum_v2` is identical (except for label names) with and without  `fastmath` is set. The additional line in the Python code seems to disable it.

Comment: A trick I found out is to write `end = np.uint64(end + 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we need do not forget that

```py
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: i = np.uint64(2**64-1)

In [3]: type(i)
Out[3]: numpy.uint64

In [4]: type(i+1)
Out[4]: numpy.float64
```

My guess that `fastmath` did some downcasting to safe some time with memory allocation to speed up performance.

```py
In [1]: import numpy as np
   ...: from numba import njit
   ...: A = np.random.rand(2, 500)

In [2]: @njit('float64(float64[:, ::1], uint64, uint64)', fastmath=True)
   ...: def fast_sum(array_2d, start, end):
   ...:     s = 0.0
   ...:     for i in range(start, end):
   ...:         s += array_2d[1][i]
   ...:     return s
   ...: 

In [3]: %timeit fast_sum(A, 100, 300)
171 ns ± 1.12 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000,000 loops each)

In [4]: @njit('float64(float64[:, ::1], uint64, uint64)', fastmath=True)
   ...: def fast_sum_v2(array_2d, start, end):
   ...:     end = end + 1
   ...:     s = 0.0
   ...:     for i in range(start, end):
   ...:         s += array_2d[1][i]
   ...:     return s
   ...: 

In [5]: %timeit fast_sum_v2(A, 100, 299)
228 ns ± 1.85 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

In [6]: @njit('float64(float64[:, ::1], uint32, uint32)', fastmath=True)
   ...: def fast_sum_v2_with32(array_2d, start, end):
   ...:     end = np.uint32(end + 1)
   ...:     s = 0.0
   ...:     for i in range(start, end):
   ...:         s += array_2d[1][i]
   ...:     return s
   ...: 

In [7]: %timeit fast_sum_v2_with32(A, 100, 299)
172 ns ± 0.687 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000,000 loops each)

In [8]: ## Here as you can see we have same time with fast_sum

In [9]: ## To fix v2 function we will advice about type of end variable for fastmath

In [10]: @njit('float64(float64[:, ::1], uint64, uint64)', fastmath=True)
    ...: def fast_sum_v2_fixed(array_2d, start, end):
    ...:     end = np.uint64(end + 1)
    ...:     s = 0.0
    ...:     for i in range(start, end):
    ...:         s += array_2d[1][i]
    ...:     return s
    ...: 

In [11]: %timeit fast_sum_v2_fixed(A, 100, 299)
173 ns ± 1.98 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000,000 loops each)
```

Some investigation and gotchas was took from here: [Numba fast math does not improve speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67743726/numba-fast-math-does-not-improve-speed)

Comment: The only reason the uint8 example is faster is because uint8(300) is 44.

Comment: @Simd Oh! You are right! 300 > 265 and 100 < 265
So start will be allocate less memory, so it will be less calculation and instruction and overall code will be faster

Comment: You mean 255, but yes.  If you delete that part of your answer I will accept in a day or so. Assuming there isn't a better answer in the meantime.

Comment: @Simd Thank you for pointing me this mistake. uint8(300) will cut end to 44 and it will limit number of iteration to 44 but not 300

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the native `np.sum` method, instead of doing the summing yourself? At least for me that is a bit faster (and much shorter code):

```
@njit('float64(float64[:, ::1], uint64, uint64)', fastmath=True)
def fast_sum(array_2d, start, end):
    s = 0.0
    for i in range(start, end):
        s += array_2d[1][i]
    return s

@njit('float64(float64[:, ::1], uint64, uint64)')
def fast_sum_faster(array_2d, start, end):
    return np.sum(array_2d[1, start:end+1])

A = np.random.rand(2, 500)
fast_sum(A, 100, 300)
%timeit fast_sum(A, 100, 300)

>>> 234 ns ± 83.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000,000 loops each)

np.testing.assert_allclose(fast_sum_faster(A, 100, 300), fast_sum(A, 100, 300))
%timeit fast_sum_faster(A, 100, 300)

>>> 210 ns ± 0.622 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
```

Comment: I will try that, thank you. I was worried start:end+1 would involve a copy but maybe numba optimizes that out.

Comment: Also end+1 is a floating point number so why doesn't that cause a problem?

Comment: I'm going to be honest, I don't know why that end+1 doesn't cause an issue as you have it in your question